# В background script замораживаются таймеры

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, background, extension

Пишу расширение для Chrome и таймеры, в том числе не высокочастотные (более 1 мин) со временем просто перестают срабатывать в background скрипте расширения.

Это случается как с SetInterval так и с SetTimeout.

Что можно с этим сделать, очень мешает нормальной работе расширения, подразумевающего автоматизированные действия каждые несколько минут?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вы правы, оформите как ответ, плюсану и отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что говорит документация на этот счет

> Use the chrome.alarms API to schedule code to run periodically or at a
>   specified time in the future.

Используйте **chrome.alarms API** для выполнения кода периодически или в определенный момент времени в будущем.

[источник](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms)